# ERROR: I don't get a bell when there's a notification from firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, notifications

I has created an application to control devices and receive notifications from Firebase. There is a problem when receive notification on Android and iOS. When application is open i can received notification with sound, but on android when app to stoped, i received notification but not have sound, when app run background i received notification and sound, on iOS when app run background and stoped, both have notification but not ring.

```
enviroment:
 react: 16.8.6
 react-native:  0.60.5,
 react-native-firebase: 5.5.6
```

Looking support to hearing from everyone. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it and my way is to create 1 new channel with priority = PRIORITY_MAX , and ios just enable sound when sending notification.

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String id = getString(R.string.channel_id);
            String name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            // Log.d("ReactNative", "MEAPP: Creating channel: " + id +", name: " + name + ", description: " + description + " .");
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.createNotificationChannel();
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ServiceUtil.createNotificationChannel(this);
    }
}
```